# ORACLE SQL Multi Join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to join fields from different tables into one doing a query with joins. From now I've only joined two tables but I have difficulties merging others more. Can you help me? These are my tables:

```
Table Departments
------------------------------------
Department_ID        Department_Name
------------------------------------
1                    Sales
2                    Marketing
3                    Warehouse

Table Roles
---------------------------------
Role_ID
---------------------------------
1
2
3
4


Table Departments_Roles
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Dep_Role_ID        Department_ID      Role_ID      Role_Name
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1                  1                  1            Admin
2                  1                  2            Client Attention
3                  2                  1            Admin
4                  3                  2            Client Attention

Table Employers
---------------------------------
Employer_Id    Employer_Name    
---------------------------------
1               John
2               Jess
3               Tom
4               George
5               David
```

What I want to see is:

```
Table Merged
-------------------------------------------------
Department_Name     Employer_Name       Role_Name
-------------------------------------------------
xxxxx               yyyyy               zzzz
```

This are just some example tables. Dont look for the sense of it.

I've tried using join, but I've never make something so complex.

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: if it's oracle, it can't be mysql nor can it be sql server. Please edit your question to include only the relevant tags.

Comment: Also, what is the connection between `Departments` and `Employers`?

Comment: You are missing a linking table or forgot to give one other table.  How does Employers relate to any of the other tables?

Comment: Can you show us your current query? Maybe it will show us where you're getting confused.

Answer (score 1):

Joining multiple tables is the same as joining one table, just repeated.

```
SELECT D.Department_Name, E.Employer_Name, DR.Role_Name
FROM Employers E --this is your base table
INNER JOIN magicalEmployerToDepartmentRoleLinkTable EDR --this connects our base table to the linking table
    ON E.Employer_Id = EDR.Employer_Id
INNER JOIN Department_Roles DR --now we can pull any column in the Department_Roles table that is related back to our base table
    ON ED.Department_Id = DR.Department_Id
INNER JOIN Department D --now we can pull any column in the Department table that is related back to the Department_Roles table
    ON DR.Department_ID = D.Department_Id
```